# "SELECT DISTINCT ON" or equivalent in Slick (v2.1)

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

In pure (Postgres-style) SQL, one can do something like the following:

```
select distinct on (author_id) author_id, title from books;
```

This would give me exactly one record from the `books` table for every author. Is there an equivalent in Scala's Slick library?  (I'm using version 2.1.0.)

Comment: Or you can port this existing SQL and focus on mapping result using Anorm.

Comment: Anorm is not really a practical option... I'm already knee-deep in Slick at this point.

Comment: Nothing really prevent mixing, at least technically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, one has to use `distinct` on an already-realized collection -- there's no way for slick to generate the SQL you want.

There is an issue on Github requesting an operation `distinct` on type `Query`:  https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/96.

Sometimes when I need vendor/SQL-specific database operations, I add a `VIEW` to the database schema and then use the `VIEW` via Slick... Maybe that's an option for you.

With Slick you can (of course) [use plain-old SQL, too](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/sql.html).

Comment: Thanks -- pretty much what I figured... I did notice that issue in Github, although it *doesn't* appear to do quite what I need; it looks as though (judging from the comments over there) it will only support distinction based on an entire row, whereas I'm looking to make distinction on a single column, whilst returning the entire row for each match.